# Identity Model invalid_client

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, identitymodel

I am just starting to learn about identity model and have been looking at the examples here - https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html

I'm looking at the simplest example - Requesting a token using the client_credentials Grant Type - and using the example code I have put together some simple vb.net to test and experiment with.

The problem I am getting is that I only ever get back an invalid_client error message.

I'm sure it is something obvious that I am missing but if someone could point me i the right direction that would be immensely helpful.

```
Dim request As New ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
request.Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token"
request.ClientId = "client"
request.ClientSecret = "secret"
request.Scope = "api1"

Dim client As New HttpClient        
Dim response As TokenResponse = Await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(request)
```

Comment: Does the client have permission to request `api1` scope? There's only `api` scope listed in [id server demo page](https://demo.identityserver.io/). You need to change `api1` -> `api`

Comment: Thanks for the link to the id server demo page. You were indeed correct that api1 should be api. Also i had the client id  wrong, needed to be 'm2m'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the reply by @abdusco the correct code should look like

```
Dim request As New ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
request.Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token"
request.ClientId = "m2m"
request.ClientSecret = "secret"
request.Scope = "api"

Dim client As New HttpClient        
Dim response As TokenResponse = Await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(request)
```

Thank you for the help.